# Is there a security risk when building an internet radio player in Visual Basic?

Tags: security, virus, visual-studio, visual-basic

I have built a simpel internet radio player in Visual Basic. It contains a couple of buttons and a webbrowser. My firewall asks for permisson to access the internet. Is it safe to allow a homemade program to access the internet or can the computer be vournable for threats?

```
Private Sub btnBanditClassics_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBanditClassics.Click
    WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed() = True
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://tunein.com/radio/Bandit-Classics-s228322/")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your firewall asks for permission because, while you are embedding IE in your app and, as far as I can tell, IE is what's accessing the internet, your app is the one required to have permission on behalf of IE.

Regarding security: No, it's not safe for a homemade program to access the internet. Security is hard even for experts.

That said, based on the code you've presented, you're unlikely to have a problem outside of whatever security issues IE has.

Comment: It is notable that when calling a webservice with defined interfaces and semantics, it is reasonably safe to consume that service within your app, but general purpose web browsing is somewhat more complex. It is also notable that the ,Net webBroiwserControl is written by MS and is as strong as any other browser they distribute.

Comment: Thank you! My english is not the best, but I assume (trying to translate/understand your answers to my language) that it's ok to allow the program cause it uses IE and depends on its security.

Comment: @MJK That is correct.